Is $n\log n + n\log \log n = \Theta(\log n)$?
To show $n\log n + n \log(\log n) = \Theta(\log n)$. Is this even correct? It can be easily shown that, $n \log n + n \log(\log n)$ is $O(n\log n)$ and also $\Omega(n\log n)$, with constants $2$ and $1$ respectively and $n > 1$. Now, $\Theta( \log(n))$ seems to be a stretch. Kindly advise.

As you stated, $n\log n + n \log \log n = \Omega(n\log n)$. Now, recall that $\Omega$ notation indicates an asymptotic lower-bound. This means that for sure $n\log n + n \log \log n$ can't be asymptotic to $\log n$, which grows way slower than $n \log n$.
As you stated, $n\log n + n \log \log n = \Omega(n\log n)$ and $n\log n + n \log \log n = O(n\log n)$, so we have that $n\log n$ is both an asymptotic lower-bound and upper-bound, which means it is $\Theta(n \log n)$.
If you want to be more precise, we can say that:

$n\log n + n \log \log n = \Omega(n\log n)$ means that $n\log n + n \log \log n$ is bounded below by $n\log n$ asymptotically (by a constant factor $k_1$).
$n\log n + n \log \log n = O(n\log n)$ means that $|n\log n + n \log \log n|$ is bounded above by $n\log n$ asymptotically (by a constant factor $k_2$).

Thus, we can conclude that $n\log n + n\log \log n$ is bounded both from below and above by $n\log n$, thus $n\log n + n\log \log n = \Theta(n \log n)$.
If you want a faster solution, we can say that, since $\log \log n \leq \log n$, we have:
$$n\log n + n \log \log n \leq n\log n + n\log n = 2n\log n = \Theta(n\log n) \ .$$

Thank you so much. This convinced me that it is indeed  Theta of nlogn.
